# Getting object value in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have two entities - User and Subscription - where Subscription contains an instance of User (named `user`). I'm trying to get all Subscriptions for a given user id with the following query:

```
SELECT sub FROM Resolute\ApiBundle\Entity\Subscription sub WHERE sub.user.id = 1
```

However it seems `sub.user.id` is not the way to access this - what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the User object first:

```
SELECT s FROM Subscription s JOIN s.user u WHERE u.id = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: Warning: class_parents(): Class Entity\user does not exist and could not be loaded in /vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222. Any advice?

Comment: Found the issue, the metadata for Subscription was incorrect (targetEntity="user" rather than targetEntity="User") - thanks for your help!